# Progress bars while jsp page is loading

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, progress-bar

I've  a jsp page which internally calls few java classes before it renders the content on the browser. The whole process is taking 1-2 minutes, so I want to show some progress bars or animations (preferably progress bar). Have gone through few posts in Stackoverflow and couldn't get much.

Have tried pace.js and few javascript and jquery techniques but couldn't get the desired effect.

It would be great if someone here help me with some ready made code snippets or the links or some tricks which help me in solving this problem.

Note: I've not used any servlet, completely used scriptlets .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add a simple loading item to the page is with a gif image. I would use jQuery to show the gif and when the content is ready hide it.

I found this snippet, it could be helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/msjaiswal/FAVN5/

```css
.loadinggif {
    background:url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat right center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inputsource' />
<br>
<button onclick="$('#inputsource').addClass('loadinggif');">Show Loading</button>
<br>
<button onclick="$('#inputsource').removeClass('loadinggif');">Hide Loading</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got one on my JSP.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name=uploadSapFile  action="sapFileUploader.jsp" method="POST" onsubmit="block();">     
   <table border=0 width="50%">   
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="process" type="submit" value="PROCESS"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>

   <img id="ajax-loader" src="../../../images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display: none;" />

   <script type="text/javascript">

   function block() {
       // This will add a "processing" animation while the system is busy with the file and also makes a "PROCESS" button deselected 
       document.getElementById('ajax-loader').style.display='block';
   }
   </script>
</form>
```

U are interested in the first line where `onsubmit` form action is performed, `img` tag and javascript function and process button.

And big choice of nice animations [here](http://www.ajaxload.info/)